# MQTT and Mosquitto broker not working in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, mqtt

I have install mosquitto broker which work in my command-prompt. When i try to run connect with the my react application it gives "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1883/' failed: "

[image: cmd]

as it works in cmd

This is the code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import mqtt from 'mqtt'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [client, setClient] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!client)
      setClient(mqtt.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883', {
      clientId: 'my-client',
    })); // Update with your broker details
    else {
      client.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to MQTT broker');
      });

      client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
        console.log('Received message:', message.toString());
      });
      return () => {
        client.end(); // Disconnect from the MQTT broker on unmounting
      };
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw", display: 'flex', justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <button>
        Hello Word
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Below error that i am getting.

[image: err]

I should connect with mosquitto broker.
I am new to use MQTT and PUB-SUB.

Answer (score 0):

By default mosquitto is configured as follows:

- it will ONLY allow connections on `localhost`
- it will only accept native MQTT connection

Assuming you are running the broker as a Windows service, you will need to edit the `mosquitto.conf` file in the install directory to add 2 listener directives.

The first will allow native MQTT access from the network.

The second will allow access via MQTT over WebSockets (they can not share the same port number)

e.g. add the following:

```
listener 1883

listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

This will allow access on port 1883 for native MQTT and then access via MQTT over Websockers on port 1884.

You will need to change the URL in the react app to `ws://localhost:1884` (also using `localhost` is not normally a good idea for webapps as they tend to be accessed by browsers on different machines so need to use the hostname/external IP address of the machine running the broker)

Comment: Thank You @hardillb, i was missed the step to run mqtt as window service.